# subtotal large quatity of data over two columns

Tags: excel

I want to group the data in excel by cost centre and ValueofTaught so for example the first row would say business services,  14.50, £441.82, S073, September.

There is multiple departments.

I have tried to do pivot tables and subtotals but can never get it to work out.

[image]

Comment: It looks as if you want to sum valueofTaught and Amount for each cost centre, which sounds fairly straightforward with a pivot, but maybe the whole thing is repeated for different departments and months?